# Posting to WCF Service sending NULL values

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, xml, wcf

I'm trying to post to my WCF Service from an iPhone app. I have the app posting to the service and trying to send data in the form of a service data contract in XML like below:

```
NSData *myPostData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<AddMediaItem xmlns='http://www.example.com'><Item xmlns:a='http://www.example.com/MediaItem'><a:MediaType>iPhone</a:MediaType><a:Description>Description</a:Description><a:Name>Test</a:Name><a:ImageType>JPEG</a:ImageType></Item></AddMediaItem>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:myPostData];

[request setPostBody:myMutablePostData];  
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];  
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];  

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

For testing purposes, I've setup my service to return the data contract that I send to the service. However, when it returns, some of the values seem to be NULLs although from the code above, I am giving them values.

What also seems strange is that the `Name` data member always has a value, but the other 3 I'm sending return NULL or with the correct values based on the order they appear in the XML I post to the service.

Below is the code for my service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
public interface IImageDiaryService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddMediaItem", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    MediaItem AddMediaItem(MediaItem Item);

}
```

Below is my code for my MediaItem data contract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/MediaItem")]
public class MediaItem
{

    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String ImageData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String ImageType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String MediaType { get; set; }

}
```

Do let me know if you need any further code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing MediaItem not not use automatic properties (e.g set and get of properties store value to a local variable).

Comment: can you setup a regular win form or console app and try it out. What results do you get? What is the data being sent over the wire, use fiddler to check it out. It's possible your deserialization isn't working properly. Maybe namespace issue or xml issue.

Comment: what url are you calling? Should be http://domain.com/AddMediaItem I think your XML is wrong because you're trying to pass the method name as if it were a SOAP message. That won't deserialize into a MediaItem type. To verify this set a break point inside of AddMediaItem method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order is important in data contracts - by default the data members are ordered alphabetically, but you can override it by using the Order property of [DataMember]. Try reordering the fields and you'll get the values populated correctly

```
<AddMediaItem xmlns='http://www.example.com'>
  <Item xmlns:a='http://www.example.com/MediaItem'>
    <a:Description>Description</a:Description>
    <a:ImageType>JPEG</a:ImageType>
    <a:MediaType>iPhone</a:MediaType>
    <a:Name>Test</a:Name>
  </Item>
</AddMediaItem>
```

Comment: +1 Ah, I forgot about this. You are correct. Order is important.

Comment: Ah ha, that got it working. I don't think I would have ever come to that conclusion. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The DataContractSerializer **only** deserializes in the known order. As carlosfigueira says, default is alphabetical but you can specify an order. Yours aren't alphabetical and so I would expect that you are having server-side serialization issues.

I'd suggest you log what's happening server side. Is the request deserializing correctly inside your service? This will tell you where the data is going missing.